# Skim and Sublime Text 3 Multiple File Sync

Tags: compiling, forward-inverse-search

When I compile the main/master file in ST3, Skim takes me right to the page where I need. But when I use other tex files linked to the main (by using`\include`) Skim takes me either to the beginning or the end of the pdf, but never to the right page.

This is what I have in my Skim Preferences Sync. Preset: Custom, followed by Command:
`/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl`

And Arguments: `"%file":%line`

How can I have Skim open included files on the right page?

Comment: Sounds like a couple of problems, which are possibly related. Can you log the arguments passed to Skim's displayline command? It looks like you'd have to hack the [jumpToPDF.py script](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools). From the documentation there, it looks like the latest Skim now has a preset for Sublime Text, also.

Comment: How can I copy the log so you can see it. Can't find the display log. I am a beginner, so I don't know how to use the jumpToPDF.py. Skim only has a preset for version 2. I tested it, and we have the same problem in both versions.

Comment: I think you'd have to modify the jumpToPDF.py script to create a log file or print to the console. Maybe it would be easier to modify Skim's displayline script, which ST calls. Adding `echo $0 > /tmp/displayline.txt ; echo $@ >> /tmp/displayline.txt` after line 15 of `Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline` would log to `/tmp/displayline.txt`.

Comment: Just a moment while I take a look.

Comment: I am sorry, but it's too technical for me. I need to go another route.

Comment: Sorry, there's no easy way to debug this, unless you can provide an example set of .tex and .pdf files that reproduces the problem. If so, I'd be happy to take a look, at least from the Skim side.